# Does CiviCRM support LDAP?

Tags: wordpress, ldap

Does CiviCRM supporting LDAP? Can we have a connection between LDAP and CiviCRM on a WordPress website?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CiviCRM's authentication is through the CMS - so you wouldn't connect CiviCRM to LDAP, you would use LDAP to authenticate to the CMS.  All CMSes that support CiviCRM support LDAP authentication.

If you would like to use CiviCRM as your LDAP source (e.g. to populate an address book in your email client with CiviCRM contacts) you can use [ldapcivi](https://github.com/TechToThePeople/ldapcivi).